# change the color and thickness of the font border of a powerpoint wordart from vba

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How can I change the color and thickness of the font border of a powerpoint wordart from vba? I'm trying with .TextFrame.TextRange but I can't find the way

I have an old web page that generates a powerpoint file and I want to modify the border of the letter of the texts in wordart that it contains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of things that you can do in Powerpoint, you can do also in Excel (eg Wordart). So if you have Excel (or Word), do the actions you want to do there and record a Macro to get an idea about the properties you need to change.

Setting the character formatting for text can be done via `TextFrame2.Characters`. In your case, change properties of `Font.Line`.

```
Dim slide As slide
For Each slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In slide.Shapes
        If sh.HasTextFrame Then
            With sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Line
                If .Visible Then  ' Prevent changing "normal" text
                    ' Adapt the following lines to your need
                    .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent2
                    .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                    .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
                    .Weight = 1
                    .Transparency = 0
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. you have given me very good advice